# webpack: referencing DOM elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, webpack, angular, visual-studio-code

I am now requiring pretty much all of my assets using webpack and Angular 2, rather than having links to the assets in the HTML. I am having a problem inasmuch as the jQuery calls are returning no references to the DOM elements.

I have this element on my page:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked id="rememberMe">
    <label>Remember me</label>
</div>
```

and I am trying to reference this input element like this:

```
(function($) {
    console.log($('#rememberMe').length);
    $('#rememberMe').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-orange',
        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-orange',
        increaseArea: '20%'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is a contortion of the original code; the console.log() writes 0 to the console: the DOM element does not yet exist. This is legacy code that uses jQuery, which is a bit of a pain but I can cope with it. I guess the best solution would be to write this code in the component's constructor or in OnInit() hook.

Is this the only solution?

Grrr.

Comment: What kind of View Encapsulation are you using?

Comment: I've actually abandoned the idea of using jQuery. I'm refactoring it to use Angular hooks.